# How to align picture to top left corner?

Tags: align, wrapfigure, wrap

someone can tell me, why the picture isn't align to the left top corner? I want move it to place where is blue box:

[image]

```
\section{Grafika i pakiet \texttt{wrapfig}}
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{L}[0pt]{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=60pt]{test.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
Z tego właśnie powodu, a także dlatego, że druki mają sprostać
różnorakim wymaganiom oraz spełniać rozmaite funkcje, nie można
nazwać konkretnego kroju pisma zasadniczo dobrym lub złym,
użytecznym lub bezużytecznym. Pisma służące do składania tekstu 
ciągłego podlegają innym kryteriom oceny niż kroje stosowane
w nagłówkach plakatów i ogłoszeń, na okładkach książek czy
po prostu ku ozdobie.
```

Answer (score 10):

wrapfig adds the same vertical space as a `h` float, so you can locally set that to zero:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}\section{Grafika i pakiet \texttt{wrapfig}}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{L}[0pt]{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=60pt]{example-image-16x9}
\end{wrapfigure}
Z tego właśnie powodu, a także dlatego, że druki mają sprostać
różnorakim wymaganiom oraz spełniać rozmaite funkcje, nie można
nazwać konkretnego kroju pisma zasadniczo dobrym lub złym,
użytecznym lub bezużytecznym. Pisma służące do składania tekstu 
ciągłego podlegają innym kryteriom oceny niż kroje stosowane
w nagłówkach plakatów i ogłoszeń, na okładkach książek czy
po prostu ku ozdobie.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm asking you this (I've likely got it wrong), but is the `{` before `\setlength` ever closed?

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks I removed it (as simplest) although actually my initial aim was to make the setting local so as not to affect any `[h]` floats. But that is a bit tricky as starting a wrapfig paragraph a local group that you close before the next "clear" paragraph is somewhat dangerous. Safest is to not use a group and set the length before the wrapfig and set it back to the original just after `\end{wrapfig}`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi see ^^